# Replace multiple texts with their corresponding texts in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, dom, replace

How can I replace Japanese texts between   with their corresponding English texts? I have a hundreds of AliasName that I need to replace. Since I am new to python and XML, a step by step instruction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how my xml file looks like:

```
<Workspace>
    <Dataset>
        <DataElement>
            <Name>POP</Name>
            <Fields>
                <Field>
                    <Name>State</Name>
                    <AliasName>?</AliasName>  # replace to  <AliasName>State</AliasName>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <Name>City</Name>
                    <AliasName>??</AliasName>  # replace to <AliasName>City</AliasName>
                </Field>
            (...)
```

Here is how far I have came. I created a dictionary, hoping that I can use it for replace(?)

```
>>> x = ("State", "州", "City", "都市", "Town", "町")
>>> dic = dict(x[n:n+2] for n in xrange(0, len(x), 2))
>>> print dic   # Japanese appears strange in python GUI
{'Town': '\x92\xac', 'City':'\x93s\x8es', 'State': '\x8fB'}
```

I also managed to select and display all Japanese texts between `<AliasName></AliasName>`.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xdoc = minidom.parse(r"D:\Desktop\python\src\sample.xml")
workspace = xdoc.getElementsByTagName("AliasName")
for i, element in enumerate(workspace):
    print (i, element.childNodes[0].data)
```

Fom here I am stuck. How can I replace and save updates on xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Unicode strings. Define source encoding at the top of the module.
2. You could use ElementTree instead of minidom. It has nicer API.

#### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

en2jp = {u"State": u"州", u"City": u"都市", u"Town": u"町"} # English -> Japanese

tree = etree.parse(filename)
for field in tree.iterfind('.//Fields/Field'):
    name, alias = [field.find(tag) for tag in ['Name', 'AliasName']]
    if name is None or name.text is None or alias is None: continue
    alias.text = en2jp.get(name.text.strip(), alias.text)
tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

You don't need a dictionary to set text of `<AliasName>` to be equal to the text of `<Name>` tag from the same `<Field>`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")
for field in tree.iterfind('.//Fields/FieldArray/Field'):
    name, alias = [field.find(tag) for tag in ['Name', 'AliasName']]
    if name is None or alias is None: 
       continue # skip if either <Name> or <AliasName> are not found
    alias.text = name.text # set <AliasName> text to be the same as <Name>

tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Wow. A few questions.  What if the field has 8 children? Does it make difference in how you write?

Comment: @user1027101: I've updated the answer. See code after `# or` line.

Comment: @Sebastian:Thank you so much for your updates!! Now I am trying to go over but it does not let me. I get syntax error saying its invalid..when "I enter from xml.etree.cElementTree as etree"

Comment: @user1027101: I've fixed a couple of typos. You might try to fix such errors yourself. Simple errors could help you to familiarize yourself with how the code works. [I've run the code with example input](https://gist.github.com/7d8e1ebacf8ff119b1eb) It behaves as expected, but it doesn't follow requirements from the question. You should be able to change it at this point.

Comment: @Sebastian：Thank you so much for your help. After I gave a couple of tries with your example, I finally got it work! Very very exciting. Now I am moving onto my work! Well, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Sebastian: With the code above, what does the "name.text.strip()" mean? I am writing a code for my work, trying to apply your method, but something is not working.

Comment: @Sebastian:I added the xml that I am working on and the code that I wrote referring your example..if you have a chance to look at it....(git clone git@gist.github.com:2069ea6b6ae582134467.git gist-2069ea6b) Sorry I do not know how this thing works..

Comment: @user1027101: There is a `help` link under "Add Comment" button. To create the link [gist](https://gist.github.com/2069ea6b6ae582134467), just type: `[gist](https://gist.github.com/2069ea6b6ae582134467)`. Python 2.x and Python 3 are sufficiently different that you should mention which one you use in your question.

Comment: @user1027101: You could add to your code: [`help(name.text.strip)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). *"something is not working"* is a bit vague. What happens? What do you expect to happen? Provide a minimal, complete example that reproduces your problem and [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7991532/edit) (unaccepted this answer in this case) or [post a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @user1027101: I've looked at your snippet. You should get `NameError` if you run your script. Python is a case-sensitive language e.g., `alias` and `Alias` are unrelated. Also [`CapWords` are reserved for class names in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @user1027101: Read my previous comment.

Comment: @Sebastian:I just posted new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011775/replace-multiple-texts-with-their-corresponding-texts-in-xml-using-python-part # I should have made it clear earlier. <AliasName> text is not always the same as <Name> text..

Comment: @Sebastian:I did not know that the CapWords are reserved for class names in Python..thanks

Comment: @user1027101: here `'reserved'` means that pep-8 acknowledges that almost all class names follows `CapsWords` naming convention. Therefore if one sees `CapsWords` in a Python source code, one assumes that it is a class name.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the string.replace() Function?

string.replace(str, old, new[, maxreplace])
    Return a copy of string str with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.