# Replace multiple texts with their corresponding texts in XML using Python - Part 2 -

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I would like to replace a text of [aliasname](/questions/tagged/aliasname) element with a text from [name](/questions/tagged/name) if there is no corresponding key in the dictionary.

here is the xml that I am working on now.

```
- <esri:Workspace xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  - <WorkspaceDefinition xsi:type="esri:WorkspaceDefinition">   
         <WorkspaceType>esriLocalDatabaseWorkspace</WorkspaceType>       
         <Domains xsi:type="esri:ArrayOfDomain" />  
  - <DatasetDefinitions xsi:type="esri:ArrayOfDataElement">   
          - <DataElement xsi:type="esri:DEFeatureClass">   
            <CatalogPath>/FC=CHO_H12</CatalogPath>      
            <Name>CHO_H12</Name>      
            <DatasetType>esriDTFeatureClass</DatasetType>
            <DSID>8</DSID>      
            <Versioned>false</Versioned>  
            <CanVersion>false</CanVersion>
            <ConfigurationKeyword />
            <HasOID>true</HasOID>
            <OIDFieldName>OBJECTID</OIDFieldName>
            - <Fields xsi:type="esri:Fields"> 
               - <FieldArray xsi:type="esri:ArrayOfField">     
                  - <Field xsi:type="esri:Field">  
                         <Name>KEY_CODE</Name>   
                         <Type>esriFieldTypeString</Type>
                         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable> 
                         <Length>255</Length> 
                         <Precision>0</Precision>
                         <Scale>0</Scale>  
                         <AliasName>リンクコード</AliasName>   # to "KEY_CODE" 
                         <ModelName>KEY_CODE</ModelName>        
                     </Field>
                  - <Field xsi:type="esri:Field"> 
                          <Name>KEN</Name>
                          <Type>esriFieldTypeString</Type> 
                          <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
                          <Length>255</Length>
                          <Precision>0</Precision>
                          <Scale>0</Scale>
                          <AliasName>都道府県番号</AliasName>    # to "Prefecture_Code"
                          <ModelName>KEN</ModelName>          
                     </Field>
                  - <Field xsi:type="esri:Field">
                           <Name>CITY</Name>          
                           <Type>esriFieldTypeString</Type>          
                           <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>          
                           <Length>255</Length>          
                           <Precision>0</Precision>          
                           <Scale>0</Scale>          
                           <AliasName>市区町村番号</AliasName>   # to "City_code"      
                           <ModelName>CITY</ModelName>          
                           </Field>
```

I wrote;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

jp2en = {'リンクコード': 'KEY_CODE', '都道府県番号': 'Prefecture_Code',
'市区町村番号': 'City_Code'} 

    tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
    for field in tree.iterfind('.//Fields/FieldArray/Field'):
         name, alias = [field.find(tag) for tag in ['Name', 'AliasName']]
         if name is None or alias is None: continue
         alias.text = jp2en.get(name.text.strip(), name.text)
    tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

However, for the output,  a text of [aliasname](/questions/tagged/aliasname) element is replaced by a text from [name](/questions/tagged/name) even when there is corresponding key in the dictionary, jp2en like this;

```
<AliasName>リンクコード</AliasName>   Returns a text "KEY_CODE" # the text is the same for Name and a key. 
<AliasName>都道府県番号</AliasName>   Returns a text "KEN" from Name instead of a key "Prefecture_Code"
<AliasName>市区町村番号</AliasName>   Returns a text "CITY" from Name instead of a key "City_code"
```

I use python 3.2.2.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You don't need to specify `coding: utf-8` in Python 3. It is a default.

Comment: use `<xmltag>` instead of `[tag:xmltag]`. The latter is for StackOverflow tags, not xml tags.

Comment: shouldnt it be `alias.text = jp2en.get(alias.text, name.text)`?  alias.text  (i.e. <AliasName> element) seems to have keys for jp2en

Comment: for the sake of debugging can you create test file which you believe the values should be changed, and change `jp2en.get(whatever)` to `jp2en[whatever]`, then run code?  it may throw you exception that key is not found and that may give you clue where you have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (seeing that the current behaviour is not what you want) you'd like to replace a text of `<AliasName>` element with a text from `<Name>` if there is no corresponding key in the dictionary. Change this line (which doesn't change `<AliasName>` if there is no key):

```
 alias.text = jp2en.get(name.text.strip(), alias.text)
```

To:

```
 alias.text = jp2en.get(name.text.strip(), name.text)
```

If key values should come from `<AliasName>` instead of `<Name>` then replace the above line by:

```
 if alias.text is not None:
    alias.text = jp2en.get(alias.text.strip(), name.text)
 else:
    alias.text = name.text
```

Comment: @Sebastian: I am almost there. It is just that alias text is always replaced by name text even when there is corresponding key in dic..I updated the code I used and output above.

Comment: @Sebastian: It did the trick!!!! You are a life saver! Made my work so much easier. Can not appreciate you enough. Thank you!!